# CakePHP: How to retrieve data from two tables using an inner join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have two tables in a database, one as `user(id,first_name,last_name)`, and the other one as `location(id,country)`.

I need to perform an inner join with these two tables based on the condition `user.id = location.id`, and the query result should contain the columns `first_name`, `last_name` and `country`.

I have tried the following query in CakePHP:

```
$this->set('users', $this->User->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'User.id',
        'User.first_name',
        'location.country'
    ),
    array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'location',
                'alias' => 'location',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array('User.id = location.id')
            )
        )
    )
)));
```

which however produces this error:

> Unknown column 'location.country' in 'field list'

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please change to `'location'.'country'` instead of `'location.country'` while retrieving the field

Comment: Table is location or locations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your syntax is wrong because the options array should have a key for the joins. You appear to have an extra `array`. Try:

```
$this->set('users',$this->User->find('list', 
  array(
       'fields' => array('User.id', 'User.first_name','location.country'),
       'joins' => array(array('table' => 'location',
                               'alias' => 'location',
                               'type' => 'INNER',
                               'conditions' => array('User.id = location.id')
                         ))
         )
  ));
```