# CakePHP how to list 2 different table which have same table structure

Tags: cakephp, merge, cakephp-3.0

Hi I have two different comments which are separated by "user_id", "device_id".

I store a comment with user_id and a comment with device_id in two different tables.

I've used $this->TableName->find() method to get data from single table, But Now I need to get data from 2 table which are almost the same.

Is there any way to merge two data and order them by 'created' in two tables?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `union` with custom query for cakephp or follow this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981352/cakephp-how-to-retrieve-data-from-two-tables-using-an-inner-join

Comment: Thank you so much It was big help!!